# which is the best way to model a matrix in java?

Tags: java, matrix

I have to model this table:

```
--------------------------------------
| range  | X<10  | 10<X<30 | 30<X<50 |
|--------|---------------------------|
|  Y<5   |  HIGH |  MIDDLE | LOW     |
|------------------------------------|   
| 5<Y<10 | MIDDLE|  LOW    | HIGH    |
|____________________________________|
```

So I have to model it in a method that takes 2 parameters (X and Y) and return the correct value based on this table.

I thought on a map based implementation, but maybe this is not the best way.
How would you model it?

Kind regards
Massimo

Comment: In this case I'd say "some if statements" in a method. Java does not really lend itself to solving [small-one-off] problems like this. (Using a Map, n-dimensional array, or other backing makes more sense for a larger look-up but ... not so much here.)

Comment: The question would be more interesting for a big number of dimensions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about two maps?

```
Map<Range, Map<Range, String>>()
```

The `Range` will hold 2 integers (lower and upper bounds) , you will need to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` in order for the `Range` to fit the `Map' nature.

So, the first `Map` will filter by `X` and the 2nd `Map` fill get the value (HIGH, LOW, etc)

Comment: It has to be mentioned, that regions should never overlap, otherwise the `equals()` method would produce unpredicted results.

Comment: @Max, why should not they? The equals() implementation is up-to-you so you can handle the overlapping inside the equals() code.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int getYIndex(int y) {
    if (y < 5) return 0;
    if (5 < y && y < 10) return 1;
    return -1; // should never reach this case
}

private int getXIndex(int x) {
    if (x < 10) return 0;
    if (10 < x && x < 30) return 1;
    if (30 < x && x < 50) return 2;
    return -1; // should never reach this case
}
```

So then you could just have a 2D-array of Strings (String[][]), where the indices would be given from the functions above.